# How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, package-management, virtualenv

Python virtual environments are used to create isolated python environments to avoid dependency and version conflicts, and also indirectly take care of permission issues. But what is the easiest way to set it up, and use it, in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

### With [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (user friendly wrappers for the functionality of `virtualenv`)

### Install virtualenv

Install `virtualenv` with

```
sudo apt install virtualenv
```

### Install virtualenvwrapper

The reason we are also installing [virtualenvwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) is because it offers nice and simple commands to manage your virtual environments. There are two ways to install `virtualenvwrapper`:

#### As Ubuntu package (from Ubuntu 16.04)

Run

```
sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper
```

then run

```
echo "source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

#### Using pip

1. Install and/or update pip

   Install pip for Python 2 with

   ```
   sudo apt install python-pip
   ```

   or for Python 3

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pip
   ```

   (if you use Python 3, you may need to use `pip3` instead of `pip` in the rest of this guide).

   **Optional (but recommended):** Turn on bash autocomplete for pip

   Run

   ```
   pip completion --bash >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

   and run `source ~/.bashrc` to enable.
2. Install virtualenvwrapper

   Because [we want to avoid `sudo pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/1439843) we install `virtualenvwrapper` locally (by default under `~/.local`) with:

   ```
   pip install --user virtualenvwrapper
   ```

   and

   ```
   echo "export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. Source virtualenvwrapper in `.bashrc`

   ```
   echo "source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

### Setup virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper:

First we export the `WORKON_HOME` variable which contains the directory in which our virtual environments are to be stored. Let's make this `~/.virtualenvs`

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
```

now also create this directory

```
mkdir $WORKON_HOME
```

and put this export in our `~/.bashrc` file so this variable gets automatically defined

```
echo "export WORKON_HOME=$WORKON_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc
```

We can also add some [extra tricks](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tips.html) like the following, which makes sure that if `pip` creates an extra virtual environment, it is also placed in our `WORKON_HOME` directory:

```
echo "export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Source ~/.bashrc to load the changes**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Test if it works**

Now we create our first virtual environment. The `-p` argument is optional, it is used to set the Python version to use; it can also be `python3` for example.

```
mkvirtualenv -p python2.7 test
```

You will see that the environment will be set up, and your prompt now includes the name of your active environment in parentheses. Also if you now run

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

you should see a lot of `/home/user/.virtualenv/...` because it now doesn't use your system site-packages.

You can deactivate your environment by running

```
deactivate
```

and if you want to work on it again, simply type

```
workon test
```

Finally, if you want to delete your environment, type

```
rmvirtualenv test
```

**Enjoy!**

---

Thanks to the author of [this blogpost](http://web.archive.org/web/20160403233119/http://conjurecode.com/python-environment-for-ubuntu-part-1/).

Comment: `python-pip` and `python-virtualenv` are installable through the Ubuntu repsitory, no need for manual installation.

Comment: However, in Ubuntu, we recommend Ubuntu packages, for many reasons. There's nothing wrong with older versions of pip or virtualenv, they are perfectly capable.

Comment: @GerhardBurger: If you create a python3 virtualenv, it'll get a pip that works in python3. If you use Ubuntu's virtualenv to create the virtualenv, everything you've done will be contained within the virtualenv. If you start sudo easy_installing stuff, it'll leave a mess all over /usr/local, that's non-trivial to clean up, without much gain.

Comment: looks like alias is not needed now: `--no-site-packages` is default and `--distribute` deprecated

Comment: In case `mkvirtualenv test` doesn't work, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608236/eclipse-and-google-app-engine-importerror-no-module-named-sysconfigdata-nd-u

Comment: I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted/33004920#33004920) that Instructions telling `sudo pip install` are inherently wrong. What do you think about it?

Comment: This is a very answer, but it only works for Python2. Could you expand it to include Python3?

Comment: No more `sudo pip`, everybody should be happy now ;)

Comment: @GerhardBurger
`~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` seems to have /usr/bin/python hardcoded, so your instructions as is won't work with python3 and `pip3 install --user virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: @raphael Thanks for the heads up! It's not hardcoded, but if `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` is not set it executes `which python`  which will return `/usr/bin/python` since that is the default python (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/). You need to `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` to make it work, I will add that to the instructions.

Comment: Between steps 1 and 2, you can also `pip install --user pip` to get the latest version of pip as a _user_ install.

Comment: I think `pip install -U pip` is wrong without the `--user` flag. (`-U` is `--upgrade`; there's no short option for `--user`.) If you don't do `--user`, it will mess with the installation that is supposed to be managed by apt, which could put things in a weird state and probably won't work without sudo, as you mention in step 2 with virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: @mkasberg You're right, I was hoping pip would resolve this automatically based on some discussions on github. Additionally, if you do upgrade pip you would need to prepend `~/.local/bin` to your PATH otherwise `pip` will still execute the system pip. Taken together I don't think upgrading pip is worth the extra effort, so I decided to remove the upgrade pip instructions again.

Comment: The path /var/www/html/python/check/python3 (from --python=/var/www/html/python/check/python3) does not exist

Comment: I confirm this works for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Many other tutorials do not work. Thank you, @GerhardBurger

Answer (score 9):

Virtual environments offer a way for managing and isolating dependencies on a per-project basis. Moreover, they also avoid the whole `sudo pip install` situation, which is a security risk as I have explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/15003. The official Python documentation also [encourages the use of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#installing-into-the-system-python-on-linux).

The easiest way to create and use virtual environments for both Python 2 and Python 3 is to install `virtualenv` using `apt` or `apt-get`. For each Python project, create a virtualenv and then activate it. Note that the virtualenv is specific for a particular Python version. After activation, use `pip` to install Python packages as usual regardless of whether you are using Python 2 or 3; there is no need to use `pip3` for Python 3. `sudo` is only used to install `virtualenv` and is not used with `pip`, therefore avoiding the aforementioned security risk. The commands to do so are:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualenv
cd ~/desired_directory  # cd to desired_directory
virtualenv venv  # create virtualenv named venv for default system Python, which is Python 2 for Ubuntu
source venv/bin/activate  # activate virtualenv
pip install -U pip  # upgrade pip in case it is outdated
pip install desired_package  # install desired_package
```

If you would like to create a virtualenv for Python 3, replace `virtualenv venv` with:

```
virtualenv venv -p python3
```

Read more about various bells and whistles for `virtualenv` at https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/.

Comment: `source` saves me a lot of commands

Comment: OSError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/var/www/html/python/check/venv/bin/python'

Comment: @SaravananNandhan Please ask a new question with the necessary details instead.

Answer (score 5):

### With the [venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) available from Python 3.3 (and Ubuntu 15.10)

Virtual environments (venvs) are so popular that the functionality is now included in python itself (from 3.3 onwards). To use it on Ubuntu you need to install `python3-venv` (since the `ensurepip` module is not available):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

After that you can use

```
pyvenv myvirtualenv
```

to create a virtual environment called `myvirtualenv`. You can then use

```
source myvirtualenv/bin/activate
```

to activate the virtual environment. To deactivate simply type

```
deactivate
```

---

**EDIT:** 
The `pyvenv` script has been deprecated in favour of `python3 -m venv`. This prevents confusion as to what Python interpreter `pyvenv` is connected to and thus what Python interpreter will be used by the virtual environment. ([source](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.6.html#id8))

Answer (score 4):

It's easy, you install [python-virtualenv](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-virtualenv). Then you can create a virtualenv with the `virtualenv` command. See [their documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#usage) for more.