# What does my PYTHONPATH contain?

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables, python-2.7

I work on some personal python libraries and I need to display what PYTHONPATH contains and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically, the environment variable `$PYTHONPATH` is empty (try `echo $PYTHONPATH`). The actual list of folders python searches for libraries can be found with (in python):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This will consist (in search order) of the current directory, any directories in your `$PYTHONPATH`, and finally the default library directories, set by `site.py`. The main default locations are (where X.Y is the python version, eg 2.7):

```
/usr/lib/pythonX.Y (python system libraries, eg re, urllib)
/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages (python libraries installed with deb packages)
```

If you use `pip install --user` or similar to install libraries as yourself, it will also contain the user library directory:

```
/home/USERNAME/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
```

You can manipulate the `PYTHONPATH` by either setting the environment variable before you launch python (`PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/foo/bar`), or by editing `sys.path` once you've started python (`import sys; sys.path = ["/foo/bar"] + sys.path`).

However, if you want to play with your own python libraries, a good idea is to create a `virtualenv`. This is a directory in which you can play around with your own versions of python libraries without any risk of messing up the python libraries used by the system. See [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu) for information about creating and using a virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks.  Studying Programming Python 4th Edition by O'Reilly books, and it constantly refers to $PYTHONPATH as an OS variable found with os.environ.  

Spent way too long looking for an object I'm not even going to change.