# Can I install new version of python on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7, cmake

Considering that the current version on my 14.04 LTS Ubuntu of python is `2.7.6`, I need a more recent version for dealing with specific libraries (that need `>2.7.7`)...

I don't really understand. Can I upgrade to `2.7.9` or not? Is it hazardous or not? I tried with `2.7.10` but it completely breaks ubuntu (and I spent many times for fixing it).

Currently I have compile python 2.7.9 and install it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/` but installing some libraries without `pip` (in my case with `cmake`) is complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at python virtual environments.  [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu) has a guide for installing virtualenv (or another link to another guide).  Virtualenv can be used to set up isolated python environments that do not do anything to the system python.

[Here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is a guide on how to use python virtual environments.  They are extremely useful for projects that require different versions of python or python modules.