# cache/pip disabled immediately after instalation of pip

Tags: apt, python, pip

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. I installed Pyhon 2.7 through aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

now I'm trying to install pip using [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) guide. I downloaded `get-pip.py`, then I tried:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Installation worked fine, but I got these annoying warnings:

```
The directory '/home/administrator/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/administrator/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

So I uninstalled all by the following command:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

And I tried a new installation without `sudo`:

```
python get-pip.py
```

but I got the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip'
```

How can I install pip (and wheels) in a proper way with caching enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, Python 2.7 is pre-installed on every currently supported Ubuntu release already. So you would not have had to install it first. That's why `apt-get` has told you that `python is already in the newest version`.

Second, you should usually prefer the Python modules packaged for `apt` from the repositories over those you get with `pip` from PyPI, unless you rely on the features or bug fixes of the latest version. The repository versions are often more or less outdated, but proofed to be compatible with whatever other package that is requiring them.

So to install `pip` for Python 2, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

In case this old `pip` version is not working for your needs, you can later simply get the latest version (without uninstalling the old one!) using this command:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
```

Another tip for you:
You should learn about and use `virtualenv`s, virtual python environments. You can install Python modules in a viertualenv only without affecting other virtualenvs or the system. It's the safest way to prevent version incompatibilities and messing around with packages needed by the system and other programs.

Comment: Hi! When I typed `python` before installation I got an error (I don't remember a message by `apt-get` similar to what you have just cited). It seemed that python interpreter was not present. After `sudo apt-get install python` all worked fine...
According to you do not I need to uninstall python (installed by `sudo apt-get install python`)? 
So if I install `pip` through `apt-get` and later I upgrade, I get the same version of `pip` that I would have got through pip?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...anyway do you think that using aptitude will fix my problem? I thinked that my problem was related to permission on folders...

Comment: **Never do `sudo apt-get remove python`!!!** Although you say that `python` wasn't installed before, this almost can't be true without having caused severe malfunctions of many programs. You are not supposed to remove neither the `python` package (Python 2.7) nor the `python3` package (Python 3.4).

Comment: Got it! Could be a good a idea create a `virtualenv` with its own python interpreter and its packages to create a dedicated/isolated development environment?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu

Comment: To complete my comments, when I typed `python` for the very first time, I got: `The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-minimal
 * python3
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`
That's the reason why I installed an interpreter : )

Comment: Very strange... o.O

Comment: Yep... : /
Last question: why does `sudo -H` fix permissions problems on directories like `/home/administrator/.cache/`...

Comment: `sudo -H` runs the command as root, but sets the used home directory to root's home directory `/root` instead of the user's home directory `/home/YOUR_USERNAME`as normal `sudo` would do. The warning is generated by `pip` because it does not want to generate cache files in  your home directory as root which you yourself could not access as normal user.