# bash: WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs: No such file or directory

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I installed python virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on ubuntu 15.10 following the answer at [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu). The installation was successful, i.e. I can create, deactivate and work on my python virtualenvs. However since I installed it, every time I fire up the terminal I get:

```
bash: WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs: No such file or directory
```

I checked if the environment variable WORKON_HOME is set correctly by typing:

```
echo $WORKON_HOME
```

and I get as output:

```
~/.virtualenvs
```

What can I do to remove the error? Thank you

EDIT 1

The output of `grep WORKON_HOME ~/.bashrc` command is:

```
echo "export WORKON_HOME=$WORKON_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc 
source WORKON_HOME=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
export WORKON_HOME=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
export WORKON_HOME=
export WORKON_HOME=
export WORKON_HOME=
export WORKON_HOME=
export WORKON_HOME=
```

EDIT 2

I have removed the lines you (@ByteCommander) mentioned. The error does not appear anymore. However, when I edit the .bashrc file, at the end it look like this:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
export WORKON_HOME=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=
export WORKON_HOME=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
```

There are many lines that repeat. Is this normal? Shall I remove the duplicate? Thanks

Comment: Please show us the output of `grep WORKON_HOME ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @ByteCommander please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are some wrong lines in your `.bashrc` file.

Please open `~/.bashrc` in your favourite text editor and delete all these lines:

- All lines that look like this pattern:

  ```
  echo "export SOMETHING" >> ~/.bashrc
  ```

  This includes e.g. those lines from your `grep` output:

  ```
  echo "export WORKON_HOME=$WORKON_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc
  echo "export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc
  ```
- All lines that look like this pattern:

  ```
  export SOMETHING=
  ```

  This includes e.g. those lines from your `grep` output:

  ```
  export WORKON_HOME=
  ```
- This line:

  ```
  source WORKON_HOME=/home/diego/.virtualenvs
  ```

If you are not sure whether to delete a line or not, better ask before you permanently remove it. Making a backup copy of the file before starting to delete lines could also be useful.

Comment: the error has disappeared, please see the edit

Comment: Yes, remove all duplicates and remove all those lines that look like `export VARIABLE_NAME=` without a value after the equation symbol.

Comment: And as you're a new user, please accept this answer by clicking the round grey tick button on the left of it if it helped you. Thanks.