# Python virtualenvwrapper problem running the initialization hooks

Tags: bash, 16.04, python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

On a fresh install of 16.04, I am trying to install virtualenvwrapper by following [this great answer by](https://askubuntu.com/a/244642/538669) Gerhard Burger.

after configuring the `.bashrc`, whenever opening the terminal displays

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

the script location is,

```
$ sudo find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh
[sudo] password for john: 
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

contents of my `.bashrc` are,

```
export WORKON_HOME=/home/john/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=/home/john/.virtualenvs
```

here is my `pip freeze`

```
cffi==1.5.2
greenlet==0.4.9
pbr==1.10.0
readline==6.2.4.1
six==1.10.0
stevedore==1.15.0
virtualenv==15.0.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.1
```

the python interpreter's location,

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

How do I make it work?

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You might want to include a link to said answer you refer to :)

Comment: @Videonauth Thanks. I just removed the link while cleaning up.  sorry.

Comment: @John My `/usr/local/bin` indeed doesn't contain `python2.7`, and I suspect yours doesn't either. `which python2.7` says `/usr/bin/python2.7`, but I have not yet figured out how to tell `virtualenvwrapper` to look in `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @John Based on http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#python-interpreter-virtualenv-and-path, can you add `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python` to your `.bashrc` before `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`?

Comment: @edwinksl tried it, but it doesn't fix.

Comment: @John How about also adding `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` before `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`?

Comment: @edwinksl sorry to say, that too doesn't work.

Comment: @John Ah okay. I am not sure what to try next, so I will let others try instead.

Comment: I have the same problem, every time I open the terminal it displays 

`/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
`

Answer (score 37):

I am using Ubuntu server 16.04,
You should also export the python interpreter in which you've installed the 
the virtualenvwrapper

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /home/vagrant/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Make sure to replace all the paths above according to your own system. Your wrapper script might e.g. be located in `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` instead, or you might use a different interpreter or virtualenvs home, ...

Answer (score 3):

In the `.bashrc` change

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

and then make it work in the current shell by

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

---

Afterwards, change in the `virtualenvwrapper.sh`

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"
```

to this

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3)"
```

Comment: `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3)"` worked for me. I *think* this was because I had two versions of python and it needed to know to pick python3 but it was installed in the homebrew. `which python` returned `/usr/bin/python` but `which python3` returned `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

Answer (score 2):

just comment

> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

line in

> ~/.bashrc

file....it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update your PYTHONPATH environment variable. In your .bashrc, before all the virtualenvwrapper variables, add the following line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Cross-verify PATH in .bashrc with following commands:

```
which virtualenv

which virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

output of:

```
echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
```

and

```
which python3
```

should be same which is

> /usr/bin/python3

Configure the path accordingly to above results

> export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
>
> export MY_PROJECT=~/my_proj
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD=1
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV='result of which virtualenv'
>
> source 'result of which virtualenvwrapper.sh'

if after verifying path still INITIALIZATION HOOK ERROR REMAINS.

Then, In source left everthing as it is just replace `virtualenvwrapper.sh` with `virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`

Then it should work