# can't create virtual env in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python3, virtualenv

Initially I followed this user's Q&A - [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu)

but this didn't work at all. When I do

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3 test
```

I get this

```
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path
```

So I want to know

1. How to remove all the changes I did following this post
2. How to set up my environment so that I can use this tutorial:

[How to install the Django web framework on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Did you see any error messages when you tried to follow the answer?

Comment: If I want to:  [  mkvirtualenv -p python3 test ] is says [ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path]

Comment: So please tell me - can I just remove old virtulenv, and virtualenv wrapper completely and install it again without any harm?