# Ubuntu 16.04 virtualenvwrapper python3.6 path

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

I'm not sure if this should be here or in a python board however since this isn't happening anywhere else except on an Ubuntu 16.04 system I thought it might be the right place.

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server set up with Amazon Ec2.

I have installed python3.6 using the first option in the best answer here:
[How do I install Python 3.6 using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get)

I also installed pip3 using this method:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

Using pip3 I installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`

```
pip3 install virtualenv
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

I set my virtualenv directory to the home directory by adding this to my .bashrc file

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenv
```

Then reloading bash using `source ~/.bashrc`

This all works fine.

The next step when I try and run

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Which is suggested by the [packages website](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and several askubuntu articles [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu) I get this error:

```
-su: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

### Firstly what does this mean and how is it resolved?

The next issue seems related.

It does seem I now have access to virtualenvwrapper commands.

When I run

mkvirtualenv test

The env is created in the expected location however I get the following output with and error:

```
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/web/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/web/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python (you must use /home/web/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python3)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied:
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you just need to set the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` variable to be python3 before you run the `virtualenvwrapper` command.

So just add:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

to your `.bashrc`.

(From http://railslide.io/virtualenvwrapper-python3.html)

Comment: Wow! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ***Great*** first answer!  (We don't see many of those around here)  **;-)**