# apt-get upgrade does not work after updating python

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, python

I recently updated my python release from 3.8 to 3.10, using
`sudo update-alternatives --config python3`, but this seems to have caused a problem with apt somewhere. Whenever I try to run `sudo apt-get update` it works as expected. When I then try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I run into the following problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up python-apt (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-apt.postinst: 6: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-apt (--configure):
 installed python-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to reinstall python apt to fix this problem with `sudo apt install --reinstall python-apt`, I get the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for python-apt:amd64
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I am also unable to open the software updater.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is expected. APT (and many other components of Ubuntu) requires a certain version of python to function properly.

To fix the issue, rollback the default python version with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

To use python 3.10, simply use the command `python3.10` (but do not link it against `python3`, which should be `python3.8` in your case).

Alternatively, use [virtual python environments](https://askubuntu.com/q/244641/124466).

**Never change the default python version, as the system may be messed up so badly that in extreme cases, you will have to reinstall Ubuntu.** This site is filled with tears of users who deleted/changed the default python version.

Note: You can use the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to safely install multiple versions of python in LTS versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I just want to reiterate for people using the deadsnakes PPA, run it with `python3.10` or use an alias that is not `python`. The reason it says `no alternatives for python3` is that deadsnakes is not installed as an alternative version to the one you installed in apt. It is a separate package. Don't change the symlink for the stable python3 install that is maintained by apt.