# python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!

Tags: apt, python, aws

I am trying to run codecommit to pull down my project

`usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version! warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "`

I have tried to reinstall code-commit, made sure awsume-configure is up to date. So I am now at a loss as what to try. I've also installed phyton3.10

Full Error

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 323, in __getitem__
    return json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hutber/.local/bin/git-remote-codecommit", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git_remote_codecommit/__init__.py", line 177, in main
    authenticated_url = git_url(context.repository, context.version, context.region, context.credentials)
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git_remote_codecommit/__init__.py", line 207, in git_url
    token = '%' + credentials.token if credentials.token else ''
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 487, in token
    self._refresh()
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 554, in _refresh
    self._protected_refresh(is_mandatory=is_mandatory_refresh)
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 570, in _protected_refresh
    metadata = self._refresh_using()
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 290, in __call__
    return self._refresh()
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 717, in fetch_credentials
    return self._get_cached_credentials()
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 725, in _get_cached_credentials
    response = self._load_from_cache()
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 743, in _load_from_cache
    creds = deepcopy(self._cache[self._cache_key])
  File "/home/hutber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 325, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(cache_key)
```

Comment: Again: https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu