# Move installed Python3.6 to another location/folder in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, dependencies, python3, software-uninstall

Hello folks and thanks for any help,

I needed to install Python 3.6 to fiddle with a script from a few years ago and the only way I found was through make files (compiler).

Steps are explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72102435/how-to-install-python3-6-on-ubuntu-22-04

last step :

```py
cd Python-3.6.15
./configure --enable-optimizations  -with-lto  --with-pydebug
make -j 8  # adjust for number of your CPU cores
sudo make altinstall
```

Unfortunately, not being familiar with python installation, I thought it would automatically be installed in the default location such as usr/bin/Python3-6

But it got installed in my project folder.

How can I move this Python3.6 folder to the default location without having this version break down ?

I still have the Python-3.6.15.tgz file if it is simpler to reinstall it in the default location.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're going about this doubly wrong. You shouldn't try to install different versions of python like this because it can really mess up your entire system. Also it's not a good idea to try to change the path of software. If you need a specific version of python for some task, set up a virtual environment so you don't mess up the rest of your system.  See: [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu)