# Ubuntu 20.04 installed Python 3.10 not is possible run python 3.10

Tags: python

Thanks for reading my topic.
Ubuntu 20.04 installed python 3.10 from
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

When trying install an software requiring python 3.10 show an message not having python 3.10 and only the 3.8 version.
Is as if any software can't access or use installed python 3.10 or 3.12.

Is possible fix it ? Have any command or dependencie to install ?

Have an nice day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu) You should set up a virtual environment. Changing the python interpreter for your system can break the system. I recommend you uninstall what you added and remove the deadsnakes PPA. Then set up a virtual environment for whatever tasks need a different version of python.

Comment: Reinstall the OS so everything is working again and then follow @Nmath for setting you the virtual environment for the python 3.10. Can you simply fix what you did?That is a BIG MAYBE and will take quite a while and might not be something you can do. A reinstall will work.

Comment: Thanks for replying ... I will try create an environment ...